# Destringing Geojson Element for Data Driven Circle Radius

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

When I upload my geojson as a tileset into Mapbox, all fields are imported as strings. Suppose I want circles to be larger for coordinates visited more often (# of visits ranging from 10-10,000). The code I use is below. But because "visits" was imported as a string, all coordinates are plotted with the same circle size on my map.

```
'circle-radius': ["sqrt", ["/", ["get", "visits"], 10000]  ],
```

How do I destring "visits" so that circle radius can vary? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple, use a `to-number` expression to convert your strings:

```
[
  "sqrt",
  [
    "/",
    ["to-number", ["get", "visits"]],
    10000
  ]
]
```

See the documentation here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#expressions-types-to-number

But as Andrew suggests below: You should probably find a way to conserve the numbers when importing as a tileset.

Comment: Although it would be better to use Numbers in your GeoJSON to start with, practically I'm not sure how much performance you loose by doing an on the fly string to number.

Comment: Added your comment to my answer, so other people can find it more easily.